# What's the origin of rc, rc.d, share, proc in Linux?

Tags: directory-structure, conventions

I still can't figure out many abbreviations' origin like `rc`, `rc.d`, `share`, `proc`...

I've heard someone says `rc` is "run command", `.d` is directory, but I'm not sure that's true.

Is there a table explaining what their source is?

Comment: For the names of common files and directories, browse the [tag:directory-structure] tag on this site.

Answer (score 8):

`rc` is actually a fossil of an old batch facility, a `runcom`; the following is a quote from Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie:

> There was a facility that would execute a bunch of commands stored in a file; it was called runcom for "run commands", and the file began to be called "a runcom". rc in Unix is a fossil from that usage.

`.d` is a standard method to differentiate between a file and directory (as directories are a type of file, so they must have different names). It's often used to indicate that the files in that directory will be sourced for some purpose, usually to allow for modular configuration.

There is a good factsheet on stuff like this at the [Indiana University website](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abnd.html).

Comment: yes, another one perhaps is `rc` file is `read configuration` file, but runcom relation is more correct. +1 Chris :-)

Comment: share and proc are obvious: share - accessible by any user usually. It is not an abbreviation. Proc comes from processes, and you will find all the running processes there, by number, id, name, etc.

Comment: @PatkosCsaba - You won't find "all running processes there"... `proc` is process *accounting*.

Comment: thanks. but i'm sorry that i think the page at Indiana University website is too few. it still lack a lot of thing like etc, tee, usr...

Comment: Most standard directories (like /proc, /usr, and /etc) are explained in depth at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/. Explanation of commands can be found on Google or in the command's man page.

Comment: I'm more interested in what these names come from. I've tryed google but it's not good at this

Comment: by the way, `man hier` can display description of the file system hierarchy, but not for my question

Comment: I've edited my question more precise